# How to make round circle UIButton with different height and width in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Is it possible to set corner radius to make `UIButton` circle using different height and width of `UIButton` in Swift.

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 40))
button.layer.cornerRadius = button.layer.bounds.size.width / 2
button.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

It won't work because button with different height and width. Please tell me if there is any other approach because button height and width going to be update. I need to make the button always be a circle.

Comment: NO there is no other way. By the way how you can treat rectangle as a square?

Comment: If you have different height and width, you simply *cannot* end up with a circle - that's a rule of geometry. You can get an oval or "lozenge" shape. The best you can do is take the *larger* of the two dimensions and set a corner radius to be half of that.

Comment: If the width and height aren't equal then it isn't a circle, it is an elipse.

Comment: If you would make your button to be a perfect circle, the button should be a square (height = width), or you would need to crop it based on which value of both height and width are longer...

Comment: *How to make round circle with different height and width?* Build a multiverse-traveling spaceship and find a universe where this is possible.

Comment: To get a perfect circle, you must have height = width. Try making height equals width and then do the corner radius = size*.5

Answer (score -1):

**TRY THIS:**

```
let myFirstButton = UIButton()
myFirstButton.setTitle("SUBMIT", forState: .Normal)
myFirstButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
myFirstButton.frame = CGRectMake(15, 50, 100, 100)
myFirstButton.layer.cornerRadius = yourButton.bounds.size.width / 2
self.view.addSubview(myFirstButton)
```

Comment: But with different height and width it is not possible i think.

Answer (score -1):

1. Make a file with name CircularButton
2. paste the code below   class
3. implement this class on the button on storyboard

Example:

```
import UIKit

class CircularButton: UIButton {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width/2
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    }
}
```